# W8-BEN form while opening a bank account

Tags: united-states, taxes

I was a student in US on F1 visa. When I opened a checking bank account, the bank took a form W8-BEN from me. Then, my visa status changed to H1B and I think that makes me resident alien for tax purposes.  So, in this case, should I resubmit W8-BEN with new visa status? As I have checking account (no interest), do I need to send W8-BEN to bank?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact the bank and let them know of the status change. Chances are it won't have any practical impact since your FATCA reporting category isn't likely to change, however each bank may handle the situation slightly differently so it's best to let them know and they will advise further on the specific next steps. (if any)